# why was en passant introduced?

Tags: rules

pawns have only one privilage and that is to move 2 squares as their first move. So why was that too taken away?
at final moment of game when we try to save our pawns to revive a queen and opposition have its pawn in my half,I cannot move ahead because of this rule.
please give me explanation on why is this rule introduced at all?